# No items for you to review

Tags: support, review

I was just reviewing the posts and after a few questions, I got the message "There are no items for you to review".

I logged in again after a day and found the same message. Why is it so?

Is it because all the posts have been reviewed or I've completed my quota?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that all the posts have been reviewed. For example, when you clicked on the Review page you can see how many posts that needs a review. After you have done the reviews for all the posts, then it shows the message "There are no items for you to review", i.e. that the posts are all reviewed.

After you logged in again after a day there might be a possibility that there is just simply no posts for you to review since they are all reviewed by other users in the community.